# Structuring time-series data in ArangoDB

Tags: time-series, data-modeling, graph-databases, arangodb, aql

I have some time-series data (roughly on the order of 1-5 points per day) I need to be able to quickly access in a webapp using ArangoDB. The data is associated with a particular profile, but one collection is used for all the data for all profiles. Between the profile node and the data node, there is a report node and an event node. The report is simply a group of data points from a given event. The existing graph structure looks like this:

```
profile =====> event1 ========> reportA =======> data1
     \             \                   \=======> data2
      \             \
       \             \========> reportB =======> data3
        \                              \=======> data4
         \
          \==> event2 ========> reportA =======> data1    
                   \                   \=======> data2
                    \
                     \========> reportB =======> data3
                                       \=======> data4
```

The chart I would like would effectively present `data1` sequentially, by associated event, sorted by an attribute of the event. An analogous tabular structure of the result set I would like looks like this:

```
event      dataAttr     value
-------------------------------
event1     data1        42
event2     data1        6
event3     data1        7
event4     data1        343
```

I am likely to run this query for every `dataAttr` in a given report, to effectively create a time-series result set for each `dataAttr` on a particular profile for the last 10-20 events.

When investigating this problem in Neo4J, they recommended directly connecting sequential events to each other. I'm wondering if this is also a better approach in ArangoDB.

This would mean creating an additional graph that looks something like this:

```
data1 (of event1) => data1 (of event2) => data1 (of event3) => data1 (of event4)
data2 (of event1) => data2 (of event2) => data2 (of event3) => data2 (of event4)
```

Etc.

Each `dataAttr` is connected to its cousin in the previous event, thus after traversing to the most recent event in the first graph, the second graph would be used to traverse n-layers to past events (practically 10-20).

Is this probably the best way to structure the data for a query like this? Performance will be critical as I potentially will be loading 20 charts on a page that each are fed by this query.

Would this query be faster simply querying on a document collection with indices rather than via graph traversal? The document collection structure could put a hash index on the `dataAttr` and skiplist on the event (they will be sequentially ordered with string sorting).

I'm assuming that traversing down to `data1` of `event1`, back up to `profile`, and back down `event2` `data1` and so on would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is critical, then trying to handle as much as possible using indexes is paramount. Traversals are superior if you have an unknown path length, which is not your use-case.

I would recommend denormalizing the data stored in the data node. You want to return all data nodes belonging to a `profile` and a given `dataAttr` sorted by a time-stamp `timeStamp`, right? In this case I would at least add the profile identifier to the data node and use a skip-listed index on `profileId`, `dataAttr` and `timeStamp`.

Comment: So upon traversing to the data desired initially, the time-series query is purely a document search? And due to the indices on documents, that'll be faster than traversing down the adjacent data?

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea. Basically, the Neo4J approach is pointing the same direction, in that case a poor man's implementation of a sorted index using a linked-list.

Comment: Cool! This is working well for us. Thank you! Another great benefit of ArangoDB's multi-model functionality!